# Why do string.split() results include undefined?

Tags: javascript, regex, undefined

I would like to split a string on either `%\d+` or `\n`.  I was able to successfully split on either one of these two, but not on both:

```
> msg = 'foo %1 bar \n baz %2'

> msg.split(/(%\d+)/)
["foo ", "%1", " bar 
 baz ", "%2", ""]

> msg.split(/(\n)/)
["foo %1 bar ", "
", " baz %2"]

> msg.split(/(\n)|(%\d)/)
["foo ", undefined, "%1", " bar ", "
", undefined, " baz ", undefined, "%2", ""]
```

In the last case, why is `undefined` in the resulting array, and what should I be doing?

**Update**: I neglected to state that I need the delimiters.  The result I want is:

```
["foo ", "%1", " bar ", "\n", " baz ", "%2"]
```

Comment: Capturing groups that did not capture any value do yield `undefined`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Quoting the [**MDN doc**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) for `String.prototype.split`:

> If separator is a regular expression that contains capturing
>   parentheses, then each time separator is matched, the results
>   (including any undefined results) of the capturing parentheses are
>   spliced into the output array.

The point is that *any* capturing group is spliced - even the one that misses the target. The first `undefined` in your example is the 'nothingness' matched by `\n` (split occured when `%\d` matched), the second is for `%\d` (when `\n` was matched)... you see the picture.

To solve this, you can get rid of capturing groups (as alternation operator has the lowest precedence anyway):

```
msg.split(/\n|%\d/); // ["foo ", " bar ", " baz ", ""]
```

If you do need that separating parts as well, use just a single capturing group:

```
msg.split(/(\n|%\d)/); 
// ["foo ", "%1", " bar ", "\n", " baz ", "%2", ""]
```

Comment: Thank you.  I neglected to state that I need the items I split on.  I will update my question.

Comment: Thanks.  I didn't understand precedence well enough to know to omit the parentheses around the disjuncts.